# How to install a libc6 version >= 2.29?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, r

When I type

`sudo apt-get install r-base-core`

I get the following error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
     r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed`

Now libc6 as far as I understand is an important library which should not be removed.

So how to upgrade from the current version (2.27) to any version >= 2.29?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
Some reported that their systems crashed after using this answer.
So anyone who is trying this, please be careful and make sure you create backups before trying it.

---

To my knowledge, libc6 2.29 is the latest version. And it is available for Ubuntu 19.04 ([link](https://pkgs.org/download/libc6)).

If you want to install **libc6 amd64**, open this [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) to download it, then open the download folder in the terminal and run `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`

If you want to install **libc6 i386**, you can download it from this [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_i386.deb), then open the download folder in the terminal and run `sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.29-0ubuntu2_i386.deb`

---

**EDIT 06/01/2020:**

As per now, **libc6_2.29** does *not exist* anymore. However libc6_2.30 and lib6_2.31 are available via this [link](https://pkgs.org/download/libc6) (2.31 is the official version for Ubuntu 20.04).
If you want to download a different version than the official one supported by your Ubuntu release (i.e 2.27 for 18.04, 2.30 for Ubuntu 19.10 ...) check [this link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/).

Download the version that suits you, then open the download folder and run `sudo dpkg -i <the_file_name>`.

Comment: I think this is not safe! Look out people what you are doing!! You can run multiple glibc (libc) versions on 1 system. HOWEVER.. keep in mind to put them in to a different folder. And use PatchELF tool to change the path, or change the dynamic linker path during the build.

Comment: @danger89 please post an answer with more details, thank you. Or you can suggest edits to my answer in order to fix the problem.

Comment: @singrium, Link is not available now

Comment: @XueQing Check the links posted in the edit of 06/01/2020. I check both links and they work.

Comment: don't do it, it has broken my system to the point it cannot even boot https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314766/whole-system-is-broken-after-failed-libc6-upgrade-attempt

Comment: *NOT SAFE*. This approach `sudo dpkg --auto-deconfigure -i libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.4_amd64.deb ` crashed my sudo setup and my system is crashed. I cannot even run `sudo` // `sudo: pam_open_session: Module is unknown sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization`.

Comment: @alper Thank you for reporting this, I have added a warning that this method let to systems crashing for some users.

Comment: This is a manual installation of libc6 package, I think it's not safe, that's why we're using `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`
But none of these too didn't worked for me, for this matter

Answer (score 7):

Don't do it. Here I'll leave an image of how dependent are your software packages on `libc6` compiled for that specific library!!! https://sites.google.com/view/dependency-netwok/.

There you'll see a star shaped network and the node at the center (green colored) represents `libc6`. I suggest two possible solutions to your problem:

**1. Add a compatible repository**

Since it is r-base-core what you want, change the repository to a compatible one for your specific distribution.

For example: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/`

In your /etc/apt/sources.list file. By using  you will be automatically be redirected to a nearby CRAN mirror. See https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html for the current list of CRAN mirrors.

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-recommended
```

**2. Upgrade**

Another solution would be to upgrade your entire distribution to a more recent and compatible with what you want.

Comment: glibc uses versioned symbols. Newer versions are usually very good at being backwards compatible with programs that were linked with an older version. Still, caution is advisable of course.