# GLIBC_2.27 not found Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, glibc

One of the software I want to run needs GLIBC_2.27, and all I see is this error on the console:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.27" not found
```

When I run this command `ldd --version` I get this output:

```
ldd(Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11) 2.23
```

How can I update GLIBC to 2.27 and get rid of the above error?

Comment: I've seen references to this problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143268/how-to-install-a-libc6-version-2-29. If you want to try it, here's the direct download link to v2.27: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb.

Comment: Just don't uninstall libc6 from your system. Do a dry run of apt-get purge instead and measure the risks. It is better not to mess with such packages because they will render the system completely unusable and unbootable. Newer versions of libc6 might be incompatible with your system.