# Whole system is broken after failed libc6 upgrade attempt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, glibc

I needed to upgrade libc6 from 2.27 to 2.31, but it was not working with `apt-get install` (it claimed 2.27 is the newest version which is not true) so as suggested by this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143268/how-to-install-a-libc6-version-2-29) I've downloaded deb package of libc6 and ran:

`sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure libc6_2.31-9_amd64.deb`

it threw some errors about incorrect dependencies, but after that I could not do anything because when using `sudo` it started to throw: `sudo 3 incorrect password attempts` every time (even though I did not enter any password).

At this point, with lack of other options I just rebooted the PC hoping it will fix itself, but now the system is stuck in some kind of loop, the screen is blinking all the time as it tries to start and I cannot do anything at all.

I guess the only way out of this is by using Recovery Mode, but which option should I choose?

Comment: libc6 version 2.27 = Ubuntu 18.04. libc6 version 2.31 = Ubuntu 20.04. Trying to install a wrong-version libc6 is like a brain transplant: The patient is unlikely to survive; the few survivors will be horribly disfigured and afraid of fire. Advice: Backup your data and then install the proper version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Read the rest of the the thread, its strongly recommended you don't do that.

You have probably broken the system quite badly, to fix you should run a temporary Ubuntu from a USB device.

Once you have a desktop you can use (running from a USB) install the original libc to the harddisk, you will have to use the `dpkg` from the temporary ubuntu because if you chroot everything will be broken.

Find your system's `/` and mount it.

you will need to use dpkg's

--instdir=dir

and avoid running any scripts in the libc deb since they will likely be dependent on libc in some way.