# run VirtualBox with Kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, ubuntu-mate

I am on an unfortunate text adventure getting to run **VirtualBox 6.1.22** under **Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS**. My key problem is, that I had to upgrade my (shiny new) machine to **Kernel 12.4** (shiny new graphics card and other hardware requiring a higher kernel...)

```
frank@p14:~$ uname -r
    5.12.4-051204-generic
```

I followed the [official Virtual Box instructions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions) (adding to sources.list, adding key) and manage to install version 6.1.22, which [explicitly supports Kernel 5.12.](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/04/virtualbox-6-1-20-released-kernel-5-11-5-12-support/).

( SecureBoot in BIOS is OFF. Just saying. )

**The warning I get during install is:**

> This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
> Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
> for adding new hardware support to the system.
>
> The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
>
> linux-headers-generic    linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic

**...fair enough, and also upon starting `$> virtualbox` I get...**

> WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
> available for the current kernel (5.12.4-051204-generic) or it failed to
> load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
>
> ```
> sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
> ```
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

...and indeed inside the Virtualbox GUI I can do little more than opening the 'about' box...

Those headers [appear available here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.4/), very first link even:

[image]

**However they won't install without a libc6 2.33 **

[image]

Fiddling the hard way with libc6 versions [sounds not like a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/1143273), or is it?

Are those “headers” available as a binary elsewhere? (my poor memories of C/C++ coding would tell me, that header files itself don't need compilation, but well in this context I have no clue what they are anyway...)

If this is the valid method to find out, I am on libc verison 2.31, so just two microversions below.

```
> ldd --version
>     ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
```

So behaps I may dare upgrade? Or is this dangerous? Or fiddle with the header package (how?) to accept 2.31? (wildly guessing there is no vital feature hidden in that minor upgrade...)

---

**Addendum**

```
$> sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
    linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0.77.80).
```

...and `/sbin/vboxconfig` keeps complaining as above (since 5.4.0 is below 5.4.12).

Trying to install the required explicit version explicitly fails, but with some additional info:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic
    ...
    Package linux-headers-5.12.4-051204-generic is not available, 
    but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been
    obsoleted, or is only available from another source
```

Hmm... should I maybe add another repo to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

**Any other suggestions?**

Comment: > However they won't install without a certain c-library (?).
Do you get an error message?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The `.deb` installer tells me and refused to install. I forgot the screenshot, now added.

Comment: What happens if you do a `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic` followed by `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`?

Comment: @vidarlo on `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic` I am being told, that I `linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0.77.80)`. And vboxconfig complains, since this is 5.4.0, wanting 5.4.12... (also added above)